# UISearchBar - coloring the search text

Tags: xcode, search, uisearchbar

I have an application in which I use UISearchBar. Everything works fine, just need to search text, for example, colored blue. **Example:** If you enter into UISearchBar "cod" will appear, for example, the word "xcode" (because "cod" contains) and I needed to "cod" colored blue and the "x" and "e" remained original. Sorry for my English.

**Code of my searchBar:**

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = true;
        filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (Slova* slova in self.slovoArray)
        {
            NSRange nameRange = [slova.slovo rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSWidthInsensitiveSearch ];


            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [filteredTableData addObject:slova];
            }
        }
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible unless you subclass the search bar and replace it's UITextField with a UITextView and then subclass the UITextView to act as the search bar's text field. It's quite a hassle, so if you don't absolutely need it, you shouldn't spend time implementing it.

I know it's not what you're looking for, but you can change the colour of all the text in the UITextField like this:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```